# Label for Loop in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, stored-procedures

The official documentation of MySQL says that using label for `LOOP` statement is optional. But when I used `LOOP` statement in a **stored procedure** without a label, an error occurred. The SQL script file is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS loop_demo $$
CREATE PROCEDURE loop_demo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE sum INT;
    SET i = 0;
    SET sum = 0;
    LOOP
        IF i > 10 THEN LEAVE ;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
        IF (i MOD 2) THEN ITERATE ;
        ELSE
            SET sum = sum + i;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    SELECT sum;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL loop_demo();
```

This is a simple loop which finds the sum of even no.s less than or equal to 10. But when I run the program the following error message generated:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
        IF (i MOD 2) THEN ITERATE ;
        ELSE
        ' at line 8
```

What could have went wrong?

Comment: The label isn't optional for "leave".

Comment: Does it mean if we gonna use `LEAVE` in a `LOOP` then we must use a 'Label'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are basically missing a label for the loop. It should be declared when the loop starts, and referred to in the `ITERATE`, `LEAVE` and `END LOOP` statements. I would also recommend not naming your variable `sum`, since it conflicts with a SQL keyword.

Consider:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE loop_demo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE sm INT;
    SET i = 0;
    SET sm = 0;
    lbl: LOOP
        IF i > 10 THEN LEAVE lbl;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
        IF (i MOD 2) THEN ITERATE lbl;
        ELSE
            SET sm = sm + i;
        END IF;
    END LOOP lbl;
    SELECT sm;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fMMW2oJ9HtRtaAGK3pYgbk/0)**